# How can I change from accepting input to check input from the list?

Tags: python

This is my list of input.

```
class TestCase:
  def __init__(self,input,output):
    self.input = input
    self.output = output
    
testCases = []
t1 = TestCase((1,[''],['6 6'],['0 8 9 2 7 5'],['5 4'],['5 3'],['1 5'],['0 1'],['0 2'],['2 1']), 
                 'Case 1: 29 4')
testCases.append(t1)
```

And this is my code.

```
num = int(input())

for i in range(num):
  input()

  v, e = list(map(int, input().split()))
  values = list(map(int, input().split()))
  edges = [[] for i in range(v)]
  for j in range(e):
    f, t = list(map(int, input().split()))
    edges[f].append(t)
  
  root = 0
  total = 0
  while len(edges[root]) > 0:
    t = [(x, values[x]) for x in edges[root]]
    dst = max(t, key=lambda x:x[1])
    total += dst[1]
    root = dst[0]
  
  print("Case {}: {} {}".format(i+1, total, root))
```

The output is something like this

```
1

6 6
0 8 9 2 7 5
5 4
5 3
1 5
0 1
0 2
2 1
Case 1: 29 4
```

My question is how can I change my code from accepting input from the user to just read or check it from the list(t1). Please help. Thank you

I have one more thing. How can I make the result run and check here? I tried many times and it has a problem on line 6 which is said 'tuple' object is not callable. What should I do with all these?

```
# Test script

for i in range(len(testCases)):
  print(testCases[i].input)
  print("*** Testing program with test case no.", i)
  %timeit global output; output=solve(testCases[i].input)

  if output==testCases[i].output:
    print("Okay")
  else:
    print("Incorrect!\nExpected output:", testCases[i].output)
    print("Actual output:", output)
```

Here is the problem link
https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=666&page=show_problem&problem=3798

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That just sounds like a bad idea. And link to the problem, please.

Comment: Your code is using `input()` all over the place, so it expects its data to come from standard in. Instead just write it as a function that expects a list as a parameter and use that parameter in the function?

Comment: https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=666&page=show_problem&problem=3798 This is the problem link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the definition of the `input()` function to return values from your TestCase class.

I think I see what your input structure is all about.  The `1` at the beginning defines how many sets of data are in the test case, and the remaining values are lists containing that many items.  Since the first value is `1`, you only have one value in each secondary list. It is the first value from each list that you want to return for each call to `input` after the first one.

The "output" you show is, I'm guessing, actually user input except for the last line.  So when reading from your data set instead of taking user input, printing each value returned by your `input()` function will verify what's going on and give you the output that you show.

Here's an extended version of your code that I think does what you want.  I added a method to your `TestCase` class to return the input data for that test case, one value at a time.  I put the main body of your code in a `main()` function that accepts a `TestCase` object.  In `main()`, I overload `input()` to point to that new method inside `TestCase` to return input from the test case instead of getting it from the user.  I didn't have to change the main body of your code at all.  Here's what I did:

```
# Run the main code via the supplied "input" function.  This function's name
# shadows the global function with the same name on purpose, as the code in
# this function was originally written to only accept input from the user, and
# we're demonstrating how to allow input to come from elsewhere without changing
# the original code

def solve(input):

    num = int(input())

    for i in range(num):
        input()

        v, e = list(map(int, input().split()))
        values = list(map(int, input().split()))
        edges = [[] for i in range(v)]
        for j in range(e):
            f, t = list(map(int, input().split()))
            edges[f].append(t)

        root = 0
        total = 0
        while len(edges[root]) > 0:
            t = [(x, values[x]) for x in edges[root]]
            dst = max(t, key=lambda x: x[1])
            total += dst[1]
            root = dst[0]

        result = "Case {}: {} {}".format(i + 1, total, root)
        print(result)
        return result

class TestCase:
    def __init__(self, input, output):
        self.input = input
        self.output = output

        # Additional instance variable to track what test data value to return next
        self.input_ptr = 0

    # Additional method that returns the next test data value from the test case input
    def next_input(self):
        v = t1.input[self.input_ptr]
        r = str(v) if self.input_ptr == 0 else v[0]
        self.input_ptr += 1
        print(r)
        return r

testCases = []
t1 = TestCase((1,[''],['6 6'],['0 8 9 2 7 5'],['5 4'],['5 3'],['1 5'],['0 1'],['0 2'],['2 1']),
                 'Case 1: 29 4')
testCases.append(t1)

# NOTE: The original behavior of the main code can still be obtained by passing the standard "input"
# function to it, like this:
#
# solve(input)

# Test script
for i in range(len(testCases)):
    print(testCases[i].input)
    print("*** Testing program with test case no.", i)
    output = solve(testCases[i].next_input)
    if output == testCases[i].output:
        print("Okay")
    else:
        print("Incorrect!\nExpected output:", testCases[i].output)
        print("Actual output:", output)
```

Result:

```
1

6 6
0 8 9 2 7 5
5 4
5 3
1 5
0 1
0 2
2 1
Case 1: 29 4
Okay
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir! I have one more thing. How can I make the result run and check here? I tried many times and it has a problem on line 6 which is said 'tuple' object is not callable. What should I do with all these?  # Test script

for i in range(len(testCases)):
  print(testCases[i].input)
  print("*** Testing program with test case no.", i)
  %timeit global output; output=solve(testCases[i].input)

  if output==testCases[i].output:
    print("Okay")
  else:
    print("Incorrect!\nExpected output:", testCases[i].output)
    print("Actual output:", output)

Comment: You just want `output = solve(testCases[i].next_input)` instead of  `output = solve(testCases[i].input)`.  To not have to change the logic of your existing code, you need a function to call that acts like the `input()` function but returns your test data. 
That function is the method I added to your TestCase class.  You need to pass that method into the main `solve()` function so that it is called instead of the standard `input()` function.  I've updated my answer to include your new code after making this small change.

Comment: OMG Thank you so so much! You are the god for me. I can finally sleep in peace. I hope you have the best Christmas and new year holiday ever. Thank you again. You are the legend!

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking again sir. I am trying to add more TestCase like t1 , t2 , t3,....,t10. How should I edit it in next_input.

Comment: I would suggest that you not add more data to your first TestCase.  Instead, just create more TestCase instances...t2, t3, t4, etc.  That's super easy, right?  Your code is already set up to iterate over the `testCases` list. Just add more TestCase object instances to that.  If you want a single TestCase object to have multiple sets of data in it, that's going to be a bit harder.  Try to work it out yourself.  I bet you can get it.

Comment: But v = t1.input[self.input_ptr] only set for t1. If I wanna add t2-t10. Should I make a loop inside next_input to call for it like t(i).